# Modeling with metric units (cm)

Tags: modeling, units, dimensions

I want to model a cover for my key with exact proportions in centimeters. What tool I should use and how should I do that?

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132965/modeling-in-blender-units

Answer (score 18):

Just switch to metric units in *Properties Window > Scene > Units > Length*:

[image]

Or in versions 2.93 and above go to *Scene Properties > Units*

[image]

Comment: I would add that the user can also display the sizes of their objects on the screen by checking "Length" in "Edge info" in "Mesh Display" in the lateral N-Panel (display it with the N key)

Comment: Note that you can also set the units to be centimeters by changing the Unit Scale to 0.01

Comment: @cegaton, just curious is there a way to also display sizes via MeasureIt plugin to show up as 5cm instead of .05m? nvm i see that  you can set the Unit via getting the right panel to show up (press N if its not there), then look for MeasureIt section and set dropdown to cm.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment, @cegaton - the question was already originally about centimeters. What's 0.01 versus 1.0?

Comment: @micromachine When you set the scale to metric and the scale to 0.01m = 1cm